# How to escape $ in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I am interested in having a line like:

```
add_link_options(-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN)
```

However, in the executable, the $ gets expanded to $$. E.g.

```
15:19:52 Debug # readelf -a mybinary | egrep -i runpath
0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [$$ORIGIN]
```

It is possible to get this effect with `patchelf` after build, but would like to have it in cmake itself if possible.

I have tried things like \$, $$ and "$ORIGIN" without any luck and can't think of anything except 50¢.

This is with cmake 3.13.1.

Edit: Verbose cmake output:

```
/usr/bin/c++  -g  "-Wl,-rpath=\$$ORIGIN" CMakeFiles/mybinary.dir/....
```

Edit2: This works:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN")
...
/usr/bin/c++  -g  -Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN CMakeFiles/mybinary.dir/...
```

Comment: The `$` shouldn't be expandeed in any way. Can't you compile your program with some verbose options (ie. for make `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)` or `make verbose=1`) and see how does the linking command line look like? Are you _sure_, that `$` get's substituted by `$$`? Can you post an MCVE then, including sample source and CMakeText.txt file?

Comment: There is old discussion about using `$ORIGIN` as RPATH in CMake: https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-January/019290.html. At that time correct  typing of `$ORIGIN` depended on many things, like CMake version, executable or library. I don't know whether things have been changed in the recent CMake.

Comment: @KamilCuk, thanks for checking this. Edited the question and added verbose output and also an alternative that worked for me.